# accessing jquery form and the parent of the a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following jQuery code.

```
$('#trade-offer form').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var stock = $(this).closest('.allloopedover');
    console.log(stock);
    return;
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this,
        data: $(this).serialize() + '&action=offer',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.alert-modal').remove();
            $(this).closest('form').find('input').removeClass('form-error');
            $(this).closest('form').find('.stm-ajax-loader').addClass('loading');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(this).closest('form').find('.stm-ajax-loader').removeClass('loading');
            $(this).closest('form').find('.modal-body').append('<div class="alert-modal alert alert-' + data.status + ' text-left">' + data.response + '</div>')
            for (var key in data.errors) {
                $('#request-trade-offer-form input[name="' + key + '"]').addClass('form-error');
            }
        }
    });
    $(this).closest('form').find('.form-error').live('hover', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('form-error');
    });
});
```

And the HTML code.

```
<div id="2012 FORD SUPER DUTY F-250 XLT" data-item="B01606" class="allloopedover listing-list-loop stm-listing-directory-list-loop stm-isotope-listing-item">
    <div class="image">
        <!--Video-->
        <a href="http://x.com/listings/2012-ford-super-duty-f-250-xlt-2/" class="rmv_txt_drctn">
            <div class="image-inner">
                <!--Badge-->
                <img width="300" height="225" src="http://x.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/31-6-300x225.jpg" class="img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://x.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/31-6-300x225.jpg 300w, http://x.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/31-6.jpg 640w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="meta-top">
            <!--Price-->
            <div class="price offerc">
                <div class="normal-price">
                    <span class="heading-font offercode">
                        <a class="rmv_txt_drctn" href="#trade-offer" data-toggle="modal" data-itemname="2012 FORD SUPER DUTY F-250 XLT" data-target="#trade-offer">Offer</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Title-->
            <div class="title heading-font mmbot">
                <a href="http://x.com/listings/2012-ford-super-duty-f-250-xlt-2/" class="rmv_txt_drctn">
                    2012 FORD SUPER DUTY F-250 XLT
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the `div` code it is not complete as it did not copied the whole code which is too big but it runs inside a loop and creates all the settings differently, notice the first div which have the

```
id="2012 FORD SUPER DUTY F-250 XLT" data-item="B01606"
```

and class as `allloopedover`.

now with jQuery, I want that when I click the submit button of a popup it should pass the id and data-item of that `div`, I tried using closest but that does not seems to be working, any idea?

Comment: It should pass the `id` and `data-item` where?

Comment: Formatting code and fixing grammar.

Answer (score 1):

When you attach a submit event handler to a form, the `this` inside your handler function will be the `form` itself, and not the button that you pressed to submit the form (which could be some `div` inside the form).

Therefore, `$(this).closest`will traverse the parents of the `form`. If the `div.allloopedover` is inside the form that is being submitted, `closest` is not going to find it. If the div you're looking for is inside the form, you can get access to it with `$(this).find(".alloopedover")`. You should then be able to get the `id` and `data-item` value of that div from the jQuery object yielded by `find`.